# laravel fortify sanctum SPA issues on forge

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, fortify, laravel-forge, sanctum

My setup is working properly locally but apparently I'm getting a 401 issue on laravel forge for my laravel-fortify-sanctum

basically I use laravel fortify for authentication then sanctum to get a token after authentication process.

it works properly on my local setup but in laravel forge it's saying I'm still Unaunthenticated

laravel forge domains
api.domain.com
frontend.domain.com

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=*.domain.com


Am I missing something?
```

Comment: A few things you can try; Use diffrent session driver, it doest not require to be cookie. Write stateful domains one by one like; `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=frontend.domain.com,api.domain.com` although it doesn't give 419 you can give a shot. Are server behind proxy or load balancer?

Comment: its just standard forge setup at the moment the very basic

Comment: @tom_cruz did you manage to solve your issue?